# Как заставить остановиться отладчику, если происходит ошибка

Tags: jquery, javascript, firebug

У меня выходит ошибка, но не постоянно, а в каких то определенных случаях.
Хочу выловить этот случай.
fireBug выдает ошибку, но и код js тоже прекращает выполнение. 
Я хочу, чтобы при появлении ошибки код остановился и я смог пошагово пройтись походу для поиска ошибки

Comment: Ну так firebug же пишет что за ошибка и в каком месте она вызвана

Answer (score 2):

В fireBug есть возможность поставить BreakPoint в любом месте внутри кода javascript. При выполнении в выбранном месте код остановится и оттуда уже можно пошагово пройти по коду, и даже просмотреть значения переменных на каждом этапе.

Comment: Дело в том, что ошибка возникает, а код в том месте не останавливается.
Если я поставлю останавливаться в этой строке всегда, то это будет долго, ведь обишка появляется 1 раз из 100

Answer (score 0):

А чем вас вариант `try - catch` не устраивает? Если ловится ошибка, выводите в консоль нужные значения, останавливаете сценарий и смотрите детали.

Comment: спасибо! совсем забыл про тру катч. Буду тестить.